# I want to check duplicate values of two field in single table using Dlookup function

Tags: ms-access-2007, dlookup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYTvR.png)I need to check duplicate values in two fields on a single table. I need to check duplicate entries for particular employers' EMPNo (Employer Number) and EMPDATE(Employer Attendance Date).

I used the following code but it gives `"Data type mismatch error"`

My exsisting DLookup function is as follows;

```vb
Private Sub Command41_Click()
Dim EMP As String
EMP = DLookup("[EMPNO]", "[tbl_LEAVE]", "[EMPNO] = '" & Me.txtEMPNO & "' And LEAVEDATE= " & Me.txtDate)

End Sub
```

Comment: Asking the web for "ms access dlookup Data type mismatch error", would have shown the answer in seconds. Next question will be "ms access dlookup criterias" as actual criterias won't find any matches (even they exist).

Comment: No.It gives same error. "Run Time Error 3464

Comment: I have attached screen shot in description section.

Comment: Don't show images of text! Copy and paste the text (put code in code blocks as I did on my edit) ,so we can copy and paste too!! You asked the web for  "ms access dlookup criterias"?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, that the date criteria must be formatted properly. Also, DLookup returns *Null* when not found, and *Null* cannot be assigned to a string. Thus, apply *Nz*:

```vb
Private Sub Command41_Click()

    Dim EMP As String

    EMP = Nz(DLookup("[EMPNO]", "[tbl_LEAVE]", "[EMPNO] = '" & Me.txtEMPNO & "' And LEAVEDATE = #" & Format(Me.txtDate, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"))

End Sub
```